# jquery - collapse a panel based on document width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to shrink a panel if the document width is < 514.  The script I have that is NOT working is:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    if ($(document).width() < 514) {

            if (!$('.panel-heading').hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            // collapse the panel
                $(this).parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
                $(this).addClass('panel-collapsed');
                $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
            }

    };
});
```

and the script which is working and allows the user to manually collapse/expand the panel:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.panel-heading span.clickable').on("click", function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            // expand the panel
            $(this).parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
            $(this).removeClass('panel-collapsed');
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
        }
        else {
            // collapse the panel
            $(this).parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
            $(this).addClass('panel-collapsed');
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
        }
    });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h3>
     <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>
  </div>

 <div class="panel-body"> Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.
</div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Justin.

Comment: Are you running the `$(document).width()` check on resize or is this a first run behaviour?

Comment: Where is your first snippet (`if ($(document).width() < 514) {...}`) at? When is it being ran?

Comment: In both the working and not working snippet, you are using `$(this)` to make modifications. Notice that it is not the same element as you are evaluating `span.clickable` in one and you are evaluating `.panel-heading` the other one.

Comment: I'm running the if ($(document).width() < 514) at the top after: jQuery(document).ready(function($){                                                              I only want to check the condition on initial load and not for a resize.

Comment: can you upload html code and/or jsfiddle

Comment: Previous comment is most likely right here. Your `$(this)` is not the same context in both those sections of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace the `this` reference fot the selector you are using for the `click` event.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

if ($(document).width() < 514) {
        var tar = $('.panel-heading span.clickable');
        if (!$('.panel-heading').hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
        // collapse the panel
            tar.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
            tar.addClass('panel-collapsed');
            tar.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
        }

};
```

});